# How can I make my objects/classes more portable?

Tags: php, class, object

From my basic understanding in Object Oriented coding, PHP in my case, you want to make all your classes pretty much independent of one another.  I have just started my object oriented application so it is a great time for me to make changes in it's early stages.

Here is my situation where I break this rule or whatever you want to call it.

I have a sessions class that has a **set method** which lets me set variables to a php session and I have a **view method** which let's me view the value of a value that has already been set using the set method.  So far it probably sounds OK but then on every page of my site I need to access session data or the session objects I should say.  But then besides every page using the session objects, I also use them in all my classes that need the session value.  I believe this is where I have messed up, because now all these other classes rely on the session class.

Any ideas on if this is wrong and if it is, what are some ways I can avoid it but still have access to the session data in the other classes and still have my classes be portable plug-n-play into other future applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of relationship is called dependencies or coupling. You generally want to reduce coupling in any application (Object oriented or not). Just how to do it is perhaps the most important skill of a programmer, and can't really be summarised into a few rules.

However, at the most basic, you should try to distinguish between *essential* dependencies and *accidental* dependencies. The former is an un-solveable problem, so you shouldn't try. For example, if all your pages need access to the session, then you really can't help giving them that. But if they only need it some times, than you could try to factor your application so that this is addressed.

Another important point is to minimise the interfaces between components. If `x` is a subset of `X` and `Y` relies on `x`, then you shouldn't pass `X`. This is often a place where there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what those other classes need in order to function in terms of your domain model. Session data is an implementation detail that shouldn't affect how you design your other classes. The session object might have 100 properties, but not every class needs all 100 of those properties to work. They don't need to know if that data was persisted in sessions, cookies, flat-files, databases, or on a satellite outside earth.

A great resource I've found useful while designing classes is [this book](http://cc2e.com/), and specifically chapter 6, "Working Classes" for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could add one level of abstraction making it `WorkingClass` > `StoringMapper` > `Session`, with `WorkingClass` only calling `StoringMapper`. As such, you could easily "map" the storing process to any other class than `Session` (for example `DatabaseSession`) without any changes to `WorkingClass`.

I've written some code for it in response to another question: [Advice on framework design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838461/advice-on-framework-design/1845657#1845657)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one class using another is pure basic OO and what you'll want. Using [**Interfaces**](http://de.php.net/interface) is a way to have your concrete logic isolated while letting other classes use this component in a uniform way. A simple and common way is to use a **Factory** or **Abstract Factory** instead of directly calling constructors. You should also have a look at the **Inversion of Control** and **Dependency Injection (DI)** paradigms. [Here's a rudimentary example](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/) that could help you with your problem (but be aware, the author mixes up between Factories and DI).

A not to complex solution would be to extract an interface from your Session class. Think of what a caller would need from a session object. Then realize the interface in your class. You'll maybe want to make this class a **Singleton** (a class for which only one realization exists at runtime). Then, create a factory that instanciates your script's components. Pass the session instance to the components in the factoring method.